# Dusk to DawnFloodlight Flickering

Tags: lighting

The context is a set of outdoor stairs.

Are there any clever techniques to minimize flickering that occurs when the sun is transitioning (setting / rising)?

If not, is there a method to determine which of these floodlights have been designed to not flicker during the sun's transition?

https://www.homedepot.com/s/dusk%2520to%2520dawn%2520floodlight?NCNI-5

I am speculating that positioning or shielding the photosensor so as to minimize light originating from the bulbs is desirable.   Any links to good t fixtures / sensors, `you have installed` are appreciated.

Comment: Of the sensors I install the sensors do not cause flicker but I have seen some LED lamps that have horrible flicker problems when first turned on, if the fixture is under warranty I would return it as the flicker tends to get worse with time or I have seen that. It got so bad I had to remove the fixture.

Comment: @EdBeal   Any links to good sensors or fixtures are appreciated.  Thank you

Comment: I have had really good luck with Tork 2021 sensors for 120v circuits these are slightly cheaper than intermatic and I have had a lot of failures lately with intermatic, these are listed for 600va for LED, 2000va for tungsten. As far as quality fixtures I purchase primarily from LEDmyplace.com , mostly DLC listed fixtures so there is a 5 year warranty and the few problems I have had with shipping dammage and a failure after only a few minutes they took care of me right away. I have now ordered several hundred lamps and fixtures from them and found them to be good quality at a good price

Comment: I've never installed one that flickered.  That is the mark of *pure junk* (or just an honest defect).   I wouldn't even expect flickering from Feit Electric, and that's a pretty low bar.  Don't o keep in mind we are not a product-reco site.  I bought [this Cooper/Eaton unit](https://amzn.to/2SQKVkr) but also had 1 of 2 fail in weeks.